# T-SQL: Islands and Gaps, Start/End

Tags: t-sql, subquery, sql-server-2014, gaps-and-islands

I have a data set where I must consolidate the ranges for two particular fields.  During research, I've seen that this problem is called "Islands and Gaps".  Unfortunately, most of the IAGs concerning merging amongst a single column ("StartDate") or something.  Whereas in my problem, I have two columns which constitute a range (PlzVon- PlzBis).

I've found plenty of examples, but they all tend to be all over the place with reference to skinning a cat.  Some of them use CTEs, others use LAG/LEAD which I've never heard of till now.

I've tried repurposing one script that I've found mostly because I can understand what it's saying, but no dice.  I can see all the "pieces" of the problem (finding upper/lower endpoints, mating the two records) but I can't figure out how to form a coherent statement with it.
[image: Example]

In the above photo, I would like to combine the highlighted rows so that they are PlzVon-73000 and PlzBis-74999.  I can tell that I need either a CTE or a correlated Sub-Query and have an ON condition of b.PlzVon = a.PlzBis + 1.  But a single join wouldn't be enough as that new record could then mate with another, leading us down a nasty path of recursion and cursors.

Any help on figuring out how to merge these islands would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is unique about the two highlighted rows that can be used to determine that these two rows are to be merged into one row? What is it about the first row with PlzVon-38000 that would cause it to be excluded from being combined with the other two rows?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? Please add a corresponding tag.

Comment: It doesn't look like `gaps-and-islands` problem. Have a look at [Packing Intervals](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/sqlserver/packing-intervals/) by Itzik Ben-Gan. If you provide some sample data as text or as `INSERT` statements (not image) in the question and your expected result, there is a good chance somebody would write the working query.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov It's version 2014 and I've added the tag like you've aske.

Comment: @JohnH The ID_FI and ID_PE fields are used to identify the "entity" they point to.  I should have added that to my question.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov You were right, it's a packing intervals problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, then this is a data island problem but on a range rather than a key. The following query demonstrates how this problem can be solved using the data island approach.

```
DECLARE @SourceData TABLE 
(
     ID         INT
    ,PlzVon     INT
    ,PlzBis     INT
)
INSERT INTO @SourceData 
VALUES
(1,38000,38999),
(2,73000,73999),
(3,74000,74999),
(4,75000,75999),
(5,85000,85999);


;WITH CTE_DataIslands  -- First CTE determine the start of each new data island
AS
(
    SELECT           [Main].ID
                    ,[Main].[PlzVon]
                    ,[Main].[PlzBis]
                    ,(
                        CASE
                            WHEN (LAG([Main].[PlzBis], 1) OVER  (ORDER BY [Main].[PlzVon] ASC) + 1 ) <> ([Main].[PlzVon]) THEN 1 -- If prev record's value for ([PlzBis] + 1)  is not equal to current record [PlzVon] value then it is the start of a new data island.
                            ELSE 0
                        END
                     ) AS [IsNewDataIsland]
    FROM            @SourceData [Main]
), CTE_GenerateGroupingID
AS
(
    SELECT  ID
            ,[PlzVon]
            ,[PlzBis]
            ,SUM([IsNewDataIsland]) OVER (ORDER BY [PlzVon] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS GroupingID -- Create a running total of the IsNewDataIsland column this will create a grouping id we can now group on
    FROM    CTE_DataIslands
)
SELECT      MIN([PlzVon]) AS [PlzVon]       -- Min [PlzVon] will give the lower range
            ,MAX([PlzBis]) AS [PlzBis]      -- Max [PlzBis] will give the upper range (use min or max for any other column that should be included in the return result)
FROM        CTE_GenerateGroupingID
GROUP BY    GroupingID
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not clear what the PK was so I added an ID in my sample table

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,PlzVon int,PlzBis int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,38000,38999),
(1,73000,73999),
(1,74000,74999)

;with cte0(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N))
     ,cteN(N) As (Select Top (Select max(PlzBis)-min(PlzVon)+1 From @YourTable) 
                         N=(Select min(PlzVon)-1 from @YourTable)+Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                   From  cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4, cte0 N5, cte0 N6) 
     ,cteBase As (Select A.ID
                        ,A.PlzVon
                        ,A.PlzBis
                        ,PosNr = N.N
                        ,RowNr = N.N - Row_Number() Over (Partition By A.ID Order By N.N) 
                   From  cteN N
                   Join  @YourTable A on N.N Between A.PlzVon and A.PlzBis
                 )
Select ID
      ,PlzVon = min(PosNr)
      ,PlzBis = max(PosNr)
 From  cteBase
 Group By ID,RowNr
 Order By ID,min(PosNr)
```

Returns

```
ID  PlzVon  PlzBis
1   38000   38999
1   73000   74999
```